# SQL Server error cannot open database

Tags: sql-server, database

Helo fellow, sorry for being annoying u again =P.
Today a got a mission in the job... ¬¬'
Our system works integrated to SQL Server. There were two databases. The main one, and another "responsible" for doing some data integration stuffs...
One day, the boss decided not to use the second database anymore, and ordered the team to create a fix application that unlinked these databases. But in one of our clients the SQL Server is givin' an error message:

-[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Database 'XXX' cannot be onpened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.

I've checked the disk space and it's fine. The memory amount is ok too. And the database files, doesn't exist anymore in the SQL data folder (like we expected and the boss desired).

This error could be expected if the were references in the sql server, but the database is not atached anymore, the table 'sysdatabases' in the master database doesn't references the database...

Someone can give a clue? I'm previously thankful for any help. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like the client is running an old version of the code which is still trying to connect to the database that's been unlinked.

Comment: Humm... So u mean that this error message is not necessarily from a missing reference of the SQL Server, but when that code executes, the SQL server tries to find that database?